# find word in raw text wrap with a div

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to find an opening an closing word such as `INFO` and `ENDINFO` and wrap everything within those two words in a div with a class of `.INFO`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var content = $('.content').html();
var regex = /INFO.*ENDINFO/gi;
var info = content.match(regex);

$('.INFO').html(info);
});​
```

For examples: Before.

```
<div class="project_content"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
<br>
INFO
<br>
Hello I'm an info div
<br>
ENDINFO
<br>
Additonal content outside of info div

</div>​
```

After:

```
<div class="project_content"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
<br>
<div class=".INFO">
<br>
Hello I'm an info div
<br>
</div>
<br>
Additonal content outside of info div

</div>​
```

This doesn't seem to work. As you can see in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRHse/). Any help would be great.

Comment: `$('.INFO')` will not match any DOM elements and so does nothing.

Comment: and where's the generated `.info` supposed to go? Appended to the `body` or inside another element?

Comment: Do you mean create a new DIV, or append to an existing one with class `.INFO`?

Comment: Where the INFO content ENDINFO already sits. Currently under the image, but could be between elements as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example code, it looks like you might want to polish up on how jquery works. The selectors you used (`.INFO` and `#content`) do not match any elements within your HTML and therefore your code does nothing.

To get you started, here's one way to achieve what you've stated: http://jsfiddle.net/JRHse/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = $('#project_content').html();
    var new_html = html.replace(/(INFO((.|\s)*?)ENDINFO)/, "<div class='INFO'>$2</div>");
    $('#project_content').html(new_html);        
});
```

Here's a quick breakdown of the code:

```
$('#project_content')
```

That matches the element with `id='project_content'`.

```
var html = $('#project_content').html();
```

We target that element and store its HTML contents in the `html` var.

```
var new_html = html.replace(/(INFO((.|\s)*?)ENDINFO)/, "<div class='INFO'>$2</div>");
```

We then perform the replacement you wanted and stores the output as `new_html`.

```
$('#project_content').html(new_html);
```

Finally, we overwrite the HTML content with the modified version.

Comment: Thats fantastic. Is there a way to avoid that flash of raw text and the css? http://jsfiddle.net/QDqX4/

Comment: @uriah your fiddle's wrapper is set to `onLoad` (after images finish loading), the flash will be much smaller when you put it in no wrap (head): [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDqX4/1/)

Comment: Thanks again Shawn, I have been struggling with this for a while. And thank you for the breakdown

Answer (score 1):

'`.`' will not match `white-space` characters. Try this regexp:

```
var regex = /INFO(.|\s)*ENDINFO/gi;
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRHse/2/)